# The command "call $(ProjectDir)some_console_application.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: asp.net-core, csproj, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I get this error when trying to publish my website
The command `call c:\..\..\some_console_application.exe` exited with code 1

When i use this command `call c:\..\..\some_console_application.exe` from the CMD it works great, but it keeps failing when using it on VS publish command

**FolderProfile.pubxml** or **project.csproj**

```
<Project>
    ...
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <Exec Command="call $(ProjectDir)prebuild.exe" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I tried some commands but no luck:

1.
`<Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)prebuild.exe" />`

Answer (score 0):

ok,.. I found the answer...
sometimes answers only comes after you share others with your loads...

the error is caused by the "Exit code", if you use a console application you should add the line `Environment.exitCode=0;`
or just add the attribute `IgnoreExitCode="true"`

```
<Project>
    ......
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)prebuild.exe" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```